# Iterating over layers to export data as a CSV

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, csv, iteration, replace

I'm trying to export particular columns of data from the attribute table to a CSV, I've added in a functionality to remove the excess commas to make this easier so that I end up with two neat columns of all the data I need. I can tell the first for loop is working as its exporting the data, but it is no longer removing the commas, in the second half of the code. I am very, very new to all this.

*This is what I'm working with:*

```
layers = iface.mapCanvas().layers()

with open (r'C:\Users\James\Desktop\Computer science\Python\code\HER_results.csv', 'w') as file:    
   
    for layer in layers:
        layerType = layer.type()
        if layerType == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:

            for getDat in layer.getFeatures():
                line = '%s, %s\n'% (getDat['Name'], getDat['PrefRef'])  
                file.write(line)
```

Comment: What is an "excess comma"? The commas in your code seem to be ok. They separate different values.

Comment: What if you change the separator to semicolon like: line = f"{getDat['Name']}; {getDat['PrefRef']}\n"

Comment: Leon,  I should have said that the data in the 'name' sometimes contains multiple commas,like: "The greyfriars gate, coventry centre" or "DSS site, 1991, excavation"  I put the second forloop in to remove these excess commas, so that the name would be in one column, not spread over many.